# main class exception when running db2triples for the first time

Tags: java, maven, rdf, r2rml

I'm trying to use db2triples for the first time, which is a java / maven project.

I got information about it from [its github page](https://github.com/antidot/db2triples/).

So far, I have performed the following steps:

1. `cd /programs/db2triples-master`
2. `vim pom.xml` and added the db2triples dependency
3. `mvn compile`
4. `mvn package`
5. `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`
6. `java -cp target/dependency/*.jar:target/db2triples-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar net.antidot.semantic.rdf.rdb2rdf.main.Db2triples`

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

After googling around, this may be a classpath error, but I'm not sure. What needs to be done in order to run this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that when you run db2triples, it can't find a dependency that is needed.

One way to resolve this problem is to add the required dependencies to your class path.  Is the apache commons cli jar actually sitting in target/dependencies?

Another way to resolve this is to build a jar that has all the dependencies embedded.  The assembly plugin as a jar-with-dependencies descriptor.  Add this to your `<build><plugins>` section in your pom.

```
  <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.3</version>
     <configuration>
        <descriptorId>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorId>   
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

To build it `mvn assembly:assembly`.

You should have another jar sitting in targets named something like `db2triples-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.  Then to run the application, you just need to run `java -cp dbp2triples-<version>-jar-with-dependencies.jar net.antidot.semantic.rdf.rdb2rdf.main.Db2triples`

Answer (score 2):

According to your linked [github](https://github.com/antidot/db2triples/) page, you should get the required dependencies

> **Needed dependency**
>
> ```
> OpenRdf Sesame > 2.6.x - http://www.openrdf.org/
> Commons-cli > 1.2 - http://commons.apache.org/cli/
> Commons-logging > 1.1.1 - http://commons.apache.org/logging/
> ```

Or, if you're using maven, add `db2triples` as a dependency to your pom

> ```xml
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>net.antidot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>db2triples</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: didn't I do that? "step 2: db2triples dep", "step 3 & 4: compile and package with maven"

Comment: No, your steps above are attempting to build their project. You'd add it as a dependency to your project to use it in your project. Once you've built it, to run it you still have to specify the dependencies on your class-path.

Comment: if by add the dependency you mean edit `pom.xml` and add the db2triples dependency, then yes, I absolutely did that (step 2). `    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.antidot</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2triples</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>` what am I missing?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. To avoid even more confusion... can someone post a working pom.xml? I would be fine with a working *.jar with dependencies too)